# Precompiled headers using QT

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qmake, pch

I'm trying to learn how to use precompiled headers in Linux.
I have several QT projects, like test1, tes2, etc. All of them are using header pch.h.
I add following lines in project's .pro file:

```
CONFIG += precompile_header
PRECOMPILED_DIR = $$DIR_SRC/Tools
PRECOMPILED_HEADER += $$DIR_SRC/Tools/dp_pch.h
```

After that I run qmake and make. That creates precompiled header, but not in a way I expect: it creates separate folder in $$DIR_SRC/Tools, like test1.gch that contains file named c++, which is, I suppose, PCH itself. But that makes PCH visible only for one project and impossible to use it for another projects.

What should I do to PCH being created directly in $$DIR_SRC/Tools folder and named like pch.gch?

Comment: Step 1: Use CMake; Step 2: Use `target_precompile_headers(... REUSE_FROM ...)`

Comment: Qmake wasn't designed to do that, afaik. You have to either by custom cimpiler steps route (for each platform) or use some other build tool